# How to enumerate files from a Docker app?

Tags: asp.net, docker

I have a NET Core Windows  service which have one of methods

```
string[] GetFileList(string path){
return Directory.GetFiles(path);
}
```

I'd like to build docker image with this service. Will this method work ? I.e. enumerate files on Windows path from Linux?